# Python - Copying Columns between CSVs, but combined string/integer values copy as blank?

Tags: python, csv, arcpy

I have a master.txt file that I converted to master.csv, using comma as delimiter. I'm trying to copy only columns I want from master.csv to aircraft.csv. My first column contains such values as A1234 and CB34555, and these show up as a blank in aircraft.csv. The column header, "N-NUMBER", does show up, as does all data in other columns. How do I fix this to get my complete data?

```
import arcpy
import csv
import time

time.sleep(7)

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\final"

master = r"C:\GIS\final\MASTER.txt"
table = r"C:\GIS\final\MASTER.csv"
result = r"C:\GIS\final\aircraft.csv"
need = ["N-NUMBER", "NAME", "STREET", "STREET2", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP CODE", "REGION", "TYPE AIRCRAFT"]
StartTime = time.clock()

in_txt = csv.reader(open(master, "rb"), delimiter = ',')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(table, 'wb'))
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
del in_txt
del out_csv

EndTime = time.clock()
TotalTime = str(EndTime - StartTime)
print "Conversion Operation Complete in " + TotalTime + " seconds."

StartTime = time.clock()

with open(table) as infile, open(result, "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, need, extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)

EndTime = time.clock()
TotalTime2 = str(EndTime - StartTime)
print "Cleaning Operation Complete in " + TotalTime2 + " seconds."
```

Comment: I suspect your `master.txt` isn't a CSV file. If so - you're unnecessarily converting it... If it has headers and columns you can parse into a dict, then the rest of your code using `extrasaction='ignore'` should work as planned.

Comment: I agree with Jon. I put an answer below assuming you already made the .csv but you could bypass that step and just split things on the default delimiter of your file.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest what I think might be a much simpler way to deal with this problem without using as many python modules:

**EDIT: I added some code to extract the indices for your labels in "need" from the first row, assuming the first row is the header, and then storing these indices in "wanted"**

```
need      = ["N-NUMBER", "NAME", "STREET", "STREET2", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP CODE", "REGION", "TYPE AIRCRAFT"]


with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    header    = f.readline().split(',')  # read and split the header
    wanted    = [header.index(x) for x in need]  # get the indices you want out of the header
    rows      = f.readlines()  # creates list of each row as a string
    table     = [r.split(',') for r in rows]  # splits each row on the ','

with open(outfile, 'w') as o:
    o.write(','.join(header) + '\n')  # re-join the split header, write it
    for row in table:
        out_string = ','.join([row[idx] for idx in wanted]) + '\n'
        o.write(out_string)  # write a new csv with the columns specified in "wanted"
```

Here you are just opening the file, reading all of the data, and then writing the data you want to a new file after specifying the select indices with "wanted". This should do the job without much overhead.

Comment: I had mistakenly used `table[idx]` instead of `row[idx]` in the write portion, I have fixed this now.

Comment: I'm getting "ValueError: 'N-NUMBER' is not in list" based on the "wanted =" line. I changed it to  [need.index(x) for x in need], but that doesn't reproduce the exact list although the script runs. Apparently the way you suggested references the list "need" but doesn't find N-NUMBER in the header list? I can't see why, as N-NUMBER is the first thing the .txt file contains.

Comment: @ChristopherBeddow can you check that the first line of your file contains the column labels in "need"? I am assuming that the first line of your file contains a bunch of labels separated by "," and that they are formatted exactly as you have them in "need"

Comment: The first line contains about 25 headers, starting with N-NUMBER,SERIAL NUMBER,MFR MODEL CODE.... and contains all of the ones in the list "need". I want to only save those columns from my "need" list, while ignoring the others. N-NUMBER is the very first item in the entire .txt file, so it's definitely there.

Comment: The way it works is if you have a `header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `need = ['a', 'c']` then `wanted = [header.index(x) for x in need]` will return `[0, 2]` but this is assuming that your formatting is as you have described it.

Comment: What happens when you open the file and and do `f.readline().split(',')`, does it return a list of the headers? For example: `a='N-NUMBER,SERIAL NUMBER,MFR MODEL CODE'`; `a.split(',')` --> `['N-NUMBER', 'SERIAL NUMBER', 'MFR MODEL CODE']`, this is what should be happening on the first line if your formatting is as you say...

Comment: Here's what I discovered--for some reason, although the .txt file reads N-NUMBER, when I list headers it says '\xef\xbb\xbfN-NUMBER'. I put this in the "need" list of my original script and it all works perfectly now!

The script suggest here still was returning an aircraft.txt or aircraft.csv that had all the headers in it, not just from need. Oh well, but I'm set! Thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherBeddow Great-- I think you could go directly from text to be honest, it might be easier, as long as you know what punctuation is used to divide the fields (i.e. change `.split(',')` to `.split('<some delimiter>")`. Also, please accept the answer if it was satisfactory!